# Pythonic way of matrix multiplication with different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, performance, matrix, optimization

I have a 1800 by 1800 matrix (Rho) and loop to calculate a parameter like this:

```
for k in range(10):
    R = (-1)**k * binom(n-k, k) * binom(n - 2*k, (n-m)//2 - k) * np.power(Rho, (n - 2*k))
```

but this loop is really time-consuming. So, I am wondering if I could write it in matrix way like this:

```
R_array = np.zeros(10)
k = np.arange(10)
R_array = (-1)**k * binom(n-k, k) * binom(n - 2*k, (n-m)//2 - k) * np.power(Rho, (n - 2*k))
```

n, m are constants, say e.g. m=10, n=6.
, to eliminate the `for` loop. But as it contains the matrix `Rho`, the last part, i.e. `np.power(Rho, (n - 2*k))` goes to an error!

So, does anybody have an idea to solve it?

I tried different sort of matrix writing, but none of them worked!

Comment: Why would removing a for-loop over ten elements make any noticeable difference?

Comment: And please show a [MRE] so we can try it ourselves.

Comment: @no comment: It is actually noticeable because it is inside another loop. When it comes to 2 loops, then the calculation time noticeably increases.

Comment: Being inside another loop doesn't change the time ratio. It changes, obviously the total. If you reduce a computation time by 10% of an operation made 1000000000 times, that only reduce the computation time of the total by 10%. Here, obviously, the time consuming part is what happens inside numpy (the operations on the 1800×1800 numbers). Not what happens inside the pure python loop. Sure, that pure python loop (the iteration of 10 values, and the computation of 10 `(-1)ᵏ` or `comb(n-k,k)`, ... could be greatly reduced if they were alone. But the are alongside an operation on a 1800×1800

Comment: (...)matrix. Even if you reduce by a factor 100 what is done by the python code (the 10 iterations), it doesn't matter, if what is alongside cost 104000 times more. (real value on my PC!). You are expecting a 0,001% improvement. Even if you do that 1 billion times, it is still just a 0,001% improvement

Comment: (It would be different, of course, if you were doing the 10-iterations loops, without the `np.power`, 1 billion times, and then, the np.power only once. )

Comment: Anyway, a [mre] should be minimal sure, but also reproducible, and representative. There shouldn't be hidden reasons to discover. If rest of the code explain why optimizing the 10-iterations loop, then show the pertinent part of the rest of the code. And anyway, at least the part that make it reproducible. We don't have values for n, or m or Rho.

Answer (score 0):

You loop is time consuming because you can't compute the higher powers of `rho` in terms of already computed lower powers of rho. Instead of

```
for k in range(10):
    R = f(k) * np.power(Rho, (n - 2*k))
```

compute

```
big_rho = np.identity(...)
rho_squared = np.power(rho, 2)
for k in reversed(range(10)):
    big_rho *= rho_squared
    R = f(k) * big_rho
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can eliminate the need for a for loop, but maybe you could try vectorizing?

```
# Vectorize parts of your calculations that don't involve powers of Rho
k = np.arange(max(int((n-m)/2 + 1), 10))  
multipliers = (-1)**k * binom(n-k, k) * binom(n - 2*k, (n-m)//2 - k)

# Initialize an array to store the results
R_results = np.zeros((10, 1800, 1800))

# Loop over the elements in 'multipliers', but apply each to the whole matrix
for i, multiplier in enumerate(multipliers):
    if i >= 10:  # Assuming you want to stop at 10 like in your original loop
        break
    R_results[i] = multiplier * np.power(Rho, (n - 2*k[i]))

# If you need a cumulative result, you can sum over the first axis:
R_final = np.sum(R_results, axis=0)
```

I think in general, calculations on large matrices are time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But anyway it contains again a for loop.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying, I don't think it's possible to get rid of the for loop, but it might help speed up the calculations if you optimize by taking some calculations out of the loop.